# Extract a sub-string from a matched string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am attempting to extract a sub-string from a string after matching for `24` at the beginning of the string. The substring is a MAC id starting at position 6 till the end of the string. I am aware that a sub string method can do the job. I am curious to know a regex implementation.

String = `2410100:80:a3:bf:72:d45`

After much trial and error, this the reg-ex I have which I think is convoluted.

```
[^24*$](?<=^\S{6}).*$
```

How can this reg-ex be modified to match for `24`, then extract the substring from position `6` till the end of the line?

`https://regex101.com/r/vcvfMx/2`

Expected Results:  `00:80:a3:bf:72:d45`

Comment: `(?<=^24\S{3}).*$`? See it here: https://regex101.com/r/HqT0RV/1

Comment: I got it. No worries.

Comment: `24` matches the first _**two**_ characters (which are "2" and "4", literally and respectively). `\S{3}` matches _**the next three**_ non-whitespace characters. So far, we've consumed _**five**_ characters so the next character is in _**position #6**_. See my answer below for additional info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(?<=^24\S{3}).*$
```

Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/HqT0RV/1/

This will get you the result you expect (i.e., `00:80:a3:bf:72:d45`). However, that doesn't seem to be a valid MAC address (the `5` at the end seems to be not part of the MAC). In which case, you should be using something like this:

```
(?<=^24\S{3})(?:[0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HqT0RV/2

**Breakdown:**

```
(?<=            # Start of a positive Lookbehind.
    ^           # Asserts position at the beginning of the string.
    24          # Matches `24` literally.
    \S{3}       # Matches any three non-whitespace characters.
)               # End of the Lookbehind (five characters so far).
(?:             # Start of a non-capturing group.
    [0-9a-f]    # A number between `0` and `9` or a letter between `a` and `f` (at pos. #6).
    {2}         # Matches the previous character class exactly two times.
    :           # Matches `:` literally.
)               # End of the non-capturing group.
{5}             # Matches the previous group exactly five times.
[0-9a-f]        # Any number between `0` and `9` or any letter between `a` and `f`.
{2}             # Matches the previous character class exactly two times.
```

Comment: You are right. It should be only up to `4`. That was a copy/paste error.

Comment: Ahmed, What is the purpose of the non-capturing group? I do not see multiple groups returned. I am trying to understand where in the string is `?:` applied.

Comment: @RSSregex _"I do not see multiple groups returned"_ That's because it's a **non-capturing** group. _"What is the purpose of the non-capturing group?"_ [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/4934172) should answer your question; but in a few words, non-capturing groups are typically used when you need to _group_ part of the match but you don't want to _capture_ it separately. There are many reasons you might need to group a part of the match (e.g., repeat it, make it optional, alternation, etc.) In our case here, we need to repeat the group (which is done using `{5}`).